# DeprecationWarning: QDesktopWidget.availableGeometry(int screen) const is deprecated centerPoint = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

What is the alternative? how to use QGuiApplication and QScreen to place my QMainWindow in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to use `QGuiApplication.primaryScreen()`(or `QGuiApplication.screens()[i]` if you want to center on the i-esima screen) as I show below:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# or
# from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


def center_window(widget):
    window = widget.window()
    window.setGeometry(
        QtWidgets.QStyle.alignedRect(
            QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight,
            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter,
            window.size(),
            QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry(),
        ),
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: center_window(w))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @SomnAthPal Yes, you should test it before asking.